# css/div - Positioning divs top, left, right, bottom and the center filling the _visible_ page only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Most tell me not to create a page layout with tables but with divs and CSS. Cool - I can go with that. Sorry for a basic question.

I would like to have the center (content) stretch to left, right, top and bottom to the *visible* page. If the content grows beyond the visible page with the T,L,R,B divs, it can scroll. The left, right, top, bottom divs are fixed at their position in the *visible* page. Fiddling around, I can never get there.

Any suggestions on how to attack this?

```
|--------------------------------|  <--- Visible page
|              Top                             | 
|--------------------------------|    Right/left fixed with stretched height
|------|  Center/content  |------|    Top/bottom fixed height stretched width
|------|                  |------|
|------|         ^        |------|
|------|         |        |------|
| Left |   <--stretch-->  | Right|
|------|         |        |------|
|------|         v        |------|
|------|                  |------|
|--------------------------------|
|             Bottom             | 
|--------------------------------|
```

Below is base code with no positioning for the divs. I've played with various position/absolute/relative etc but always get some weird overflow from top and bottom divs.

```
<body>
    <style>
        .container {
            border: 3px solid #FF00FF;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .top {
            background: red;
            height: 3em;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .bottom {
            background: blue;
            height: 3em;
            bottom: 0;
        }

        .left {
            background: green;
            width: 5em;
        }

        .right {
            background: gold;
            width: 5em;
        }

        .content {
            background: lightgreen;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }            
    </style>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
            Top
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            Left
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            Content
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            Right
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            Bottom
        </div>
    </div>           
</body>
```

Comment: hello you just need to position Left and Right div (Green ,and YEllow section) correct?

Answer (score 5):

```
html, body {
 height:100%;
}
.container {
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.top {
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 background: red;
}
.left {
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;
 left:0;
 bottom:50px;
 width: 50px;
 background: green;
}
.right {
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;
 right:0;
 bottom:50px;
 width: 50px;
 background: gold;
}
.bottom {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background: blue;
}
.content {
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;
 left:50px;
 right:50px;
 bottom:50px;
 background: lightgreen;
 overflow:scroll;
}
```

Something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/kf2JP/)

*side note: height in % won't work unless it's parent element has height set explicitly...*

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
<body>
    <style>
        .container {
            border: 3px solid #FF00FF;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .top {
            background: red;
            height: 3em;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .bottom {
            background: blue;
            height: 3em;
            bottom: 0;
            width:100%;
            float: left;
        }

        .left {
            background: green;
            width: 5em;
            float:left;
            height: 100%;           
            width: 10%;         
        }

        .right {
            background: gold;
            width: 5em;
            float:left;
            height: 100%;                       
            width: 10%;         
        }

        .content {
            background: lightgreen;
            height: 100%;
            width: 80%;
            float:left;
        }            
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

    </style>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
            Top
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            Left
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            Content
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            Right
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            Bottom
        </div>
    </div>           
</body>-</body>

</html>
```

fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/sgwKe/1/